# Setting counter 0 in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, counters

I am using `tcolorbox` and I want my Theorem/Example box to start with label 0. See the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % should be before tcolorbox
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,most}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%\newcounter{mycounter}
%\setcounter{mycounter}{-1}
%\setcounter{section}{-1} 

%\newtcbtheorem[]{example}{Example}{label type=example}{exa}
\newtcbtheorem[number within = section]{example}{Example}{label type=example}{exa}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{Print a string variable.}{label}
\begin{verbatim}
city = input('Enter the name of your favourite city \n')
                  # Here city is a string variable.
                  # \n lets you type city in a new line.

print("Your fav city's name:", city)
\end{verbatim}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Here I tried to use the conventional `setcounter` and it did not work (hence commented). Could there be any easy remedy?

Comment: You can explicitly set the counter you want to use (and setting this to zero) using `\newcounter{myexa} \setcounter{myexa}{-1} \newtcbtheorem[use counter=myexa]{example}{Example}{label type=example}{exa}`.

Comment: Try this: `\newcounter{mycounter} \setcounter{mycounter}{-1} \newtcbtheorem[use counter=mycounter, number within=section]{example}{Example}{label type=example}{exa}`

Comment: Thanks, @JasperHabicht. Seems I was almost on the track, just wasn't aware of the command `use counter=`.  One step further: what if I want to keep the counter with one or two places after the decimal point? @Ignasi's answer (using `number within=section`) serves the purpose of one place after the decimal point though.

Comment: @hbaromega I suggest to ask a follow-up question, with a precise description for what "keep the counter with one or two places after the decimal point" means. A counter always holds an integer value, hence no decimal point is involved.  For the current question, you can post an answer yourself and mark it as "the" answer.